# Rails keeps erasing ar_internal_metadata table from the schema when running migration

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Whenever I run a migration on my local machine, the rails internal table `ar_internal_metadata` is removed from the schema, I've run the command:

```
bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development
```

but it doesn't seem do anything.

The table is present on production (which the main schema is from) so it needs to be there.

How do I stop this from happening, how do I put it back and is it ok to just copy and paste the table back into the schema?